# are "sort", "type" and "kind" always exchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

Cambridge dictionary has an article on "sort, type and kind" and explains that they all "generally" mean the same thing.

Based on their definitions (Merriam-Webster), indeed, they all mean more or less "a group united by common trait".

However, to the ear of native English speakers, are they unequivocally identical and exchangeable?

- Jazz isn’t the sort of music I can listen to for very long.
- Jazz isn't the kind of music I can listen to for very long.
- Jazz isn't the type of music I can listen to for very long.

- The most popular type of music in the US is not Jazz.
- The most popular kind of music in the US is not Jazz.
- The most popular sort of music in the US is not Jazz.

- There are many kinds of birds coming to feed in my garden at the moment.
- There are many types of birds coming to feed in my garden at the moment.
- There are many sorts of birds coming to feed in my garden at the moment.

Comment: I assume you exclude other meanings, like sort/arrange, type/press keys to make words, kind/generous, but you might want to state that explicitly

Comment: You'll often hear things like *My blind date last night was awful! He really wasn't my **type**!* But you'd be *very* unlikely to hear ***kind*** or ***sort*** there. And to be honest, if I heard ***You can't marry him! He's simply not your kind!*** I might suppose "he" was an alien or something ("your kind" tending to imply "humankind"). But I doubt there would ever be any difference when ***type / kind / sort*** is followed by ***...of** [relevant category name]*.

Comment: As _filler words_, kind of/kinda (\`The answer is kind of obvious.') and sort of/sorta (\`It's a sort of a hack, but you can do the following.') are common, but I have never heard type of in this role.

Comment: A very good book on the subject is Pelletier 2010, _Kinds, Things, and Stuff: Mass Terms and Generics_, Oxford U Press. There are lots more categories available, and no consistent use of any of these words exists, either in normal English, or in technical analyses. You have to look at what terms each author and school/theory use, and even then it's hard to tell.

Comment: 'There are all sorts / kinds of birds in this region' usually means  'There are many different sorts / kinds / types of birds in this region'. But 'There are all types of birds in this region' could well mean that every type is represented.

Comment: *No two words mean exactly the same thing.* They may denote pretty much the same thing in most contexts, but there are always different connotations - nuances. So no, these 3 words are not always interchangeable (or "exchangeable").